# Why is my button style not applied when declared in the resources of another style?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, hover, ismouseover

I don't understand why this doesn't change the Background and Foreground while hovering the Button. It changes the CornerRadius of the Border tho.

ButtonStyle.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="RoundedCorners">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

LoginView.xaml

```
<Button Height="50"
        Width="200"
        Style="{StaticResource RoundedCorners}">
    LOGIN
</Button>
```

Comment: What are `Primary` and `Black`? These are nowhere defined. Also, how is the Button defined?

Comment: @Lennart sorry, my mistake. I've added it to the question

Comment: Your inner Button style is not applied because there is an explicit Style already applied to the button. Move the Style triggers up to the outer style and it'll work

Comment: Like this? If yes, it doesn't seem to work aswell. :( 
[Image](https://i.ibb.co/mqXyG6d/image.png)
`<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource White}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Black}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
`

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, an explicit `Style` set locally through `Style={StaticResource StyleKey}` takes precedence over an implicit style matched through a `TargetType`, as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netdesktop-6.0#dependency-property-precedence-list).

Hence, only the outer `Style` is applied to your `Button` because it's given a key and epxlicitly set.

To fix it, you should meger the inner `Style` into the keyed `Style` like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="RoundedCorners">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This will properly change the `Foreground` when you hover it. The `Background` will still not change, but that's an entire different problem.